# Problem using cell value as sheet name to copy data to/from

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I am trying to copy dat from one sheet to another sheet that is named in cell B1.

I had my code working by setting a specific sheet name however I cannot work out how to use my B1 value as the target sheet. I now recieve an error on Line 27 where I update the target sheet.

```
    function savetodatabase() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dJ2TrQd6ZYCW9wMKh7v_pAiQbfYvm0QDjeWUypsKwHg");
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Rota");
  var sheetnamerange = source_sheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, 1);
  var sheetname = sheetnamerange.getValue();
 
var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName(sheetname);
   
  
  
  var firstrow = 1;
  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("AE10:AV");
  var bridgerange = source_sheet.getRange("C4:C7");
  var bridgedata = bridgerange.getValues()
  var data = source_range.getValues();
 savetime()
  
  target_sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, 18).setValues(data);
  target_sheet.getRange(1, 19, 1, 1).setValue("=now()");
  target_sheet.getRange(1, 20, 4, 1).setValues(bridgedata);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. If you require any more information please just ask.

Comment: Can you provide the detail information about `I now recieve an error on Line 27 where I update the target sheet.`?

Comment: There is no line 27

Comment: Oh yes, sorry it's line 27 of my full code not this function. It's says cannot read properly getRange of Null for the line:   target_sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, 18).setValues(data);

When I change the line:  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName(sheetname);  to have ("06/07/20") it works for what I want it to do. I just really need that sheetname part to be from cell B1.

Comment: Perhaps you spelled the name incorrectly or perhaps there is space and the end that you are not seeing.

Comment: I think I might have solved it. Think it was because I was using a date as the name. I presume sheets is taking is as the full date time format but my script was looking for the dd/mm/yy style. Tried it with a tet value and it worked. Only slightly annoying but excellent that I have a sort of new method to try.

Comment: In that case, when `var sheetname = sheetnamerange.getValue();` is modified to `var sheetname = sheetnamerange.getDisplayValue();`, what result will you get? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue)

Comment: I get the exact result I was after! Thank you so much